# Dynamic mod-rewrite rule for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Someone could help me to make a match-rule for my .htaccess ?

I would like that the old urls indexed on search-engines like:

```
http://www.domain.com/watch.php?id=ANY_ID
```

redirects automagically to:

```
http://www.domain.com/watch/ANY_ID
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^watch/([^/]*)$ /watch.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule watch/(.*) watch.php?id=$1
```

But is not working for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I'm not sure why questions are being named as duplicates of that question. I understand why it is being brought up (it is very helpful), but it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeRockett: This was more a case of *possible* duplicate than possible *duplicate*, if you will.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Right, understood.

Answer (score 0):

You have only included code that internally maps/rewrites the new URI to the old one. If you want to also redirect the old URI to the new onw, then you can use the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200

# Check for old URI and redirect to new URI
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\d]+)$
RewriteRule ^watch.php$ /watch/%1? [R,L]

# Map new URI to file
RewriteRule watch/(.*) /watch.php?id=$1 [L]
```